# Using RegularExpressions to Parse and Execute Method

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a mini-type scripting language for my service and I've been trying to extract data from certain strings in a line. For example:

`!d3 Profile: {D3Api("Name")}`
`!weather Current Weather {Weather("Location")}`

Working with my current code, I cannot seem to get it to find the text I'm looking for. I can probably do an `if` statement if the line contains say `{D3Api()}` or `{Weather()}` right? Anyway, here's my expression for finding text {D3Api()} and retrieving the text in that:

```
String text = "Profile: (\\{D3Api\\(\"(.?)\"\\)\\})";
Regex r = new Regex(text , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

It's not parsing or returning the text. How can I improve this?

My poorly design parsing code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    string t = "{D3Api(\"Name\")";
    String text = "(\\{D3Api\\(\"(.*?)\"\\)\\})";
    Regex r = new Regex(text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);  
    Console.WriteLine("Parsing..\n\r");
    Match m = r.Match(t);
    if (m.Success) {
            string c = m.Groups[1].ToString();
            string s = m.Groups[2].ToString();
            Console.Write("(" + c.ToString() + ")" + "(" + s.ToString() + ")" + "\n");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I'm actually answering your question, but I think your looking to have named groups. That is done with regex syntax like `(?<function>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\((?<param>[^)]\)`. With this you can set a generic format for your function names and take a single parameter. For more info on named groups take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

As an aside, if your language is complex, then you may find that RegEx isn't robust enough for your needs. In this case, I'd suggest taking a look at creating a custom syntax using EBNF, then creating a tokenizer (pretty fun project IMO). An example of this can be seen [here](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-peg.ebnf.tokenizers.html)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, EBNF seems to be the best fit for what I'm trying to accomplish! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using quantifier. You can use `*` which means match the previous token 0 or more times.

```
String text = "(\\{D3Api\\(\"(.*?)\"\\)\\})";
Regex r = new Regex(text , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

After doing the above, you can do use `Regex.Match` or `Matches` if you want multiple matches.

Comment: It's not showing any matches in my regular expressions tester. Could I be missing a token? I'm trying to get the `Name` argument in `{D3Api("Name")}`. I added my parser code to reflect your answer.

Comment: @BrandonPalmer http://regex101.com/r/qJ1hX7/1. I escaped `"` and `\` as it is necessary in c#.

Comment: Thank you sir! but I decided to use "Irony" and just make my own language for this type of thing. new Command("Hello this is the API {D1}", D3Api(String));